# can't delete Resource Records through CMD in Windows Sever 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mx-record, cname-record, windows-command-prompt

### Final Update

Problem erased in the least acceptable way: After re-installing the DNS-Server lead to even more problems, I re-installed the whole Operating System and - up to now - everything works like it should. Before anyone asks: This was/is an official download of Server 2008 from the official website, and not anything from anywhere.

---

Following [this Cheat Sheet](http://www.minasi.com/newsletters/nws0803a.htm) I'm able to set up an MX Record as other Ressource Records in Windows Server 2008 through CMD. I am also able to delete the Records through CMD and everything, EXCEPT the MX Record. This only works through the GUI. For whatever reasons.

I got that far:

Set: `dnscmd /recordadd bigfirm.com @ MX 10 mail.bigfirm.com` (works)

Delete: `dnscmd /recorddelete bigfirm.com @ MX 10 mail.bigfirm.com` → doesn't work

[[→ source](http://www.minasi.com/newsletters/nws0803a.htm) of commands]

The command seems is reported as executed properly but `dnscmd /zoneprint bigfirm.com` still lists the MX Record. Deleting it through the GUI is no problem – but also not the what I'm trying to achieve.

The `10` looks highly suspicious to me, but without it the command doesn't report successful execution – which doesn't really matter as it doesn't do what it should…

---

### UPDATE

Three days later, getting desperate... So what I did was that, step by step:

- Syntax: *dnscmd /Recordadd ZONE NODE MX PRIORITY SERVER*
  → `dnscmd /Recordadd tarpit post MX 10 mordor`
- Check what I did → `dnscmd /zoneprint tarpit` result (shortend):
  `;  Zone:    tarpit
  ;  Server:  mordor
  ;
  @ 3600 NS   mordor.
  3600 SOA    mordor. hostmaster. 2 900 600 86400 3600
  post 3600 MX 10 mordor.`
- Delete the MX Record:
  Syntax: *dnscmd /recorddelete ZONE NODE MX 10 SERVER*
  → `dnscmd /recorddelete tarpit post mx 10 mordor`
- Check what happend → `dnscmd /zoneprint tarpit` result (shortend):
  `;  Zone:    tarpit
  ;  Server:  mordor
  ;
  @ 3600 NS    mordor.
  3600 SOA mordor. hostmaster. 8 900 600 86400 3600
  post 3600 MX 10 mordor.`

I've tried a lot of combinations what to set for server, zone etc.: FQDN, with(out) a dot at the end, and whatnot… a whole trial and error session with the same result: The only way to delete the entry is via Servermanager on the GUI level.

### **What did I do wrong?!**

I would highly appreciate if somebody could tell me the correct syntax with the names I used so it would be easier for me to translate this to other situations.

I'm quite new to this all and I'm not happy. I've also tried restarting etc. Doesn't work. Only on the GUI level.

---

### Update 2:

- Turns out I can't delete ANY Resource Records via `cmd`
- **Zones I completely deleted about a week ago reappeared**, including all their fully working resource records! This suddenly happend after renaming & completely shutting down and booting the machine twice.
- Looking through cached entries the system reported that MMC is broken and I've got the following details:

> Beschreibung:   **Stopped working**
>   Problemsignatur:
>   Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
>  Application Name:  mmc.exe
>   Application Version:  6.0.6002.18005
>  Application
>   Timestamp:    49e01c0a
>  Fault Module Name: dnsmgr.dll
>  Fault Module
>   Version:  6.0.6002.18005
>  Fault Module Timestamp:  49e03737
>   Exception Code:           c0000005
>  Exception Offset:  00049e6d
>   Betriebsystemversion: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
>  Gebietsschema-ID:  1031

- This I get if I use the offered "debugging" option:

> Problemsignatur:
>   Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
>   Anwendungsname:   mmc.exe
>   Anwendungsversion:    6.0.6002.18005
>   Anwendungszeitstempel:    49e01c0a
>   Fehlermodulname:  dnsmgr.dll
>   Fehlermodulversion:   6.0.6002.18005
>   Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   49e03737
>   Ausnahmecode: c0000005
>   Ausnahmeoffset:   00049e6d
>   Betriebsystemversion: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
>   Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
>   Zusatzinformation 1:  fd00
>   Zusatzinformation 2:  ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
>   Zusatzinformation 3:  fd00
>   Zusatzinformation 4:  ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160

---

Comment: The `10` specifies mailserver priority. Zone files can have multiple MX records; if a higher-priority MX doesn't resolve, it'll try the next MX, and so on. Basically, it's supposed to be there.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 This I know, but thank you. There is only this one entry and, as an exercise, I sucessfully set but unsucessfully tried to delete it. Also interesting: Only one MX entry but without specifying it's priority I don't even get a "sucesfully executed" statement (roughly translated from the original message; not in English)

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax is

`dnscmd ServerName /recorddelete ZoneName NodeName RRType RRData[/f]`

So for example this would be:

`dnscmd /recorddelete test.contoso.com NodeServerName MX 10 mailserver.test.contoso.com`

I suspect, you are using the **@** rather then the actual **node name**?

---

Seeing that the above post hasn't helped you, I can only confirm this works on my DNS servers:

> C:\Users\Administrator>dnscmd /recordadd test1.demo.com @ MX 100 test.mailserver.com
>
> Add MX Record for test1.demo.com at test1.demo.com 
>   Command completed successfully.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>dnscmd /recorddelete test1.demo.com @ MX 100 test.mailserver.com > Are you sure you want to delete record? (y/n) y
>
> Deleted MX record(s) at test1.demo.com 
>   Command completed successfully.

Comment: For completeness' sake: `/f` stands for: "Don't bother me with asking for confirmation, just do as I told you". Also: both examples have the same source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069.aspx and yes, I got that far to look for a solution at the the official vendor's website - whicht didn't help me much and was the reason I came here for asking. Having it here through Copy & Paste as answer is at least a nice try, so thank you for that!

Comment: ah yes, thank you! It works perfectly now after re-installin the whole OS. Anyhow: Thanks, Cold T :)